# Issue Querying LDAP DirectoryEntry in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, ldap, session-variables

I have users login to my application via Active Directory and then pull from their AD information to garner information about that user like so:

```
Dim ID as FormsIdentity = DirectCast(User.Identity, FormsIdentity)
Dim ticket as FormsAuthenticationTicket = ID.Ticket
Dim adDirectory as New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com")
Dim adTicketID as String = ticket.Name.Substring(0, 5)
Session("people_id") = adDirectory.Children.Find("CN=" & adTicketID).Properties("employeeID").Value
Session("person_name") = adDirectory.Children.Find("CN=" & adTicketID).Properties("displayName").Value
```

Now, I want to be able to impersonate other users...so that I can "test" the application as them, so I added a textbox and a button to the page and when the button is clicked the text is assigned to a session variable like so:

```
 Session("impersonate_user") = TextBox1.Text
```

When the page reloads I check to see if Session("impersonate_user") has a value other than "" and then attempt to query Active Directory using this session variable like so:

```
If CStr(Session("impersonate_user")) <> "" Then
  Dim adDirectory as New DirectoryEntry(LDAP://DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com")
  Dim adTicketID as String = CStr(Session("impersonate_user"))
  Session("people_id") = adDirectory.Children.Find("CN=" & adTicketID).Properties("employeeID").Value
  Session("person_name")= adDirectory.Children.Find("CN=" & adTicketID).Properties("displayName").Value
Else
  [use the actual ticket.name to get this info.]
End If
```

But this doesn't work. Instead, it throws an error on the first Session line stating, "DirectoryServicesCOMException was unhandled by user code There is no such object on the server."
Why? I know I'm giving it a valid username! Is something strange happening in the casting of the session? The code is essentially the same between each method except that in one method rather than pulling from ticket.Name I pull from a session variable for the login I'll be looking up with AD.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the identity your process is running under needs permissions to access the active directory. You could do this by changing the identity your application runs under in the IIS application pool.

What is entered in the textbox?

Comment: Hmmm...But AD querying works fine when I set adTicketID to ticket.name, it just doesn't work when I set it to CStr(Session("impersonate_user")). In this example, the login name I would "authenticate" to the app might be bj442 and the textbox might contain the same "bj442" or someone else ("rj442")